# Windows 10 Intel AC 7260 WLAN device keeps failing

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, laptop, drivers, gateway

I have had this problem for the last year, it happened after a windows update.  Here are the specifics:

1. Wireless network connected and working fine.
2. After some random time, wireless network stops working.
3. Check WLANs and nothing is listed except the one I am connected to and state is Connected No Internet.
4. Disconnect from current network, now nothing shows in the WLAN list.
5. Execute trouble shooter which stops and starts the device and the list is restored. This error is listed as cause:  Default Gateway Not Available.

That cause is obviously total BS.  The device wasn't seeing anything, so it has nothing to do with the default gateway.  Here is what I have done in the past to resolve the issue:

1. Visit the intel site and download the latest device drivers for AC 7260.
2. Uninstall and delete the existing driver software.
3. Install latest AC 7260 drivers.
4. On the device, turn off power saving option.
5. On the Power Option plan, set the WLAN settings to Highest Performance for plug and battery.

All of this resolved the issue until I updated the Windows security patch last week.  There are no more recent Intel drivers for this device (May 2019) and the frequency of the problem increases with time.  At first it may be fixed for a day, or hours.  Then it happens in an hour.  Then it is happening every 10 minutes.

I don't want to downgrade my windows patch, but I recognize I may have no choice.  I would rather have the real fix for this problem.  There has to be something that is causing this Intel device to stop working.

Comment: “All of this resolved the issue until I updated the Windows security patch last week.” - Which update exactly?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: I have that device as an alternate connection on my desktop computer. Driver 18.33.17.1 and Windows 2004 fully up to date. Is it worth trying a new USB Wireless card as your Intel card may be failing (according to your description).

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have exactly the same problem!

Comment: I am also having the same problem.

Comment: The only solution I could find was to upgrade to the 9200 series.  The 7200 series of Intel chip would not work with later upgrades of the windows 10 operating system.